# How do you perform the likelihood ratio test in SAS?

Tags: regression, sas

I want to compare model $A$ with 5 variables and model $B$ with 3 variables. I want to use the likelihood ratio test to do this. Note that this is logistic regression. How do I do this in SAS?

Comment: Is the three variable model a sub-model of the five variable model? If so, you can take the $-2\cdot{\rm loglike}$ from the outputs and do it manually, if nothing else.

Comment: @Macro: And you use the intercept and covariates values of $-2 \log L$ for each model and divide by 2?

Comment: No. Under the null, the difference between the $-2 \log L$ values follows a $\chi^{2}_{d}$ distribution (as $n \rightarrow \infty$) where $d$ is the number of parameters deleted to arrive at the submodel. You can use the CDF of that distribution to get the $p$-value.

Answer (score 1):

See this example from the documentation which shows how to construct and compare different ROC curves for the models: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63962/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_logistic_sect066.htm

Notice in the output that each model includes the -2 log L. Also notice that the final table of this output includes the chi-square values and p-values for the pairwise comparisons.